# extending a generic class with typed method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I try to type an overwritten method in a derived class automatically to avoid repeating myself.

```
class A<T> {
  foo (bar: T) {
    return bar
  }
}

class B extends A<number> {
  // Error: bar is any instead of number
  foo (bar) {
    console.log(bar)
    return bar
  }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAZgez2gAoAjMAJwC5pEBKdLbacgUwBcBXcgO2jPMYBfDMIyhIMAELQWADzYtuAExgJuHALYkW5VJmwB6A9ADqACwCe0AJYw2Z29G542N7jh0sl0SE83byAH5GfEJSCnp9JmA8bgg8EBYAOhA8AHNw8lpGbFZOHj4KIREMDCA)

I cant figure out why the code above doesn't just work. What is the problem here? Is there a solution?

// Edit:

The question is, "what do I have to change to make it work". I don't want to write a type in the function definition because I have multiple functions with multiple parameters. I don't want to repeat myself. As a bonus I would like to understand how it works under the hood and why it doesn't work like I did it

Comment: The whole reason of this is to avoid to type everything again. In my actual application the generic is quite more complex and multiple methods use it. I don't want to repeat myself :/

Comment: If they need to match, it should only complain if I specify wrong types and otherwise assume the ones from the base class shouldn't they?

Comment: @blurfus The question is "why can't TS infer `number` parameter", not "how do I stop TS error for `any`".

Comment: What's the primary question here; is it "why doesn't it work/what is the problem" (where the answer involves https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911) or "is there a solution" which would presumably require various workaround suggestions?

Comment: @jcalz these links are very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Since it can't "just work" due to those linked issues, there are only workarounds.  The most *straightforward* workaround is to manually annotate all the subclass method parameters, but you don't want to do that.  Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVg0vm) would be more palatable? Essentially you create a class factory function to implement the abstract methods (saw in a comment that you care about abstract methods).  It's convoluted but you can get the contextual type inference you want.  If you want me to write this up as an answer I can; let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After considering [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70525862/extending-a-generic-class-with-typed-method/70526009#comment124668700_70525862) more:

> The whole reason of this is to avoid to type everything again. In my actual application the generic is quite more complex and multiple methods use it. I don't want to repeat myself :/

I think I now understand that the core of the question is more about reduction of typing than anything else. The answer to this is using a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=19#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAZgez2gAoAjMAJwC5pEBKdLbacgUwBcBXcgO2jPIDcjAL4ZRGAJbc2LcjjDAW0AAqyIeXmmjcwAWxbUIbclIDm0cS24dd0AEotwbCRogALCQAdEAT09LMbGUKKzYAGkYAZQkSEDMI7ABhPBAQFjBTDhYE6AB6XOgAOmL2YEKxDElpWXlFOCg8YAkwGXRmRxaXbncvagcnLp7vPyVRfKLi6F08VmgpGTkFJTYRiEqV-2hk3U844BaWABNoAF4VNQ1oADJ69SaDvIAqa4nC0sLoR9yhDFBIGAAQtAWAAPGTcQ4wBDbXYSfYyQ6oQK4AjEfjUGF7A6HejI7DAVwpFiFEB4UykCi0IRMdqcHh8CjUiwVX6uNh8U7aFgAd2gAKIVIwJEK+DwRGROn01AA5AARMCHQ4+aAAUVJ3GlOVYA1cHk8fQ6zl1Xl8-kKwVY0giwipeQKmLh2IwQA)

```ts
interface Person { name: string }

enum RelationshipType {
  Parent,
  Sibling,
  Colleague,
  // ...etc.
}

interface Associate { relationship: RelationshipType }
// ... more interface types

type Complicated = Person & Associate /* & ...etc. */;

class B extends A<Complicated> {
  foo (bar: Complicated) {
    console.log(bar);
    return bar;
  }
}

const b = new B();
b.foo({
  name: 'Daddy Elon',
  relationship: RelationshipType.Parent,
}); // Complicated
```

---

Do you actually need to override the method? If not, you just need to extend the base class while providing the generic type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAZgez2gAoAjMAJwC5pEBKdLbacgUwBcBXcgO2jPIDcjAL4ZRGUJBgAhaCwAebFtwAmMBNw4BbEi3Ko044Hm4Q2faAF5o3FgHdo0orSHHT51hA4hz1kgDp8PCIAFgAmF2gAeiibbV1yCRMIPBAWfxA8AHMiT282SJjocKA)

```ts
class A<T> {
  foo (bar: T) {
    return bar;
  }
}

class B extends A<number> {}

const b = new B();
const result = b.foo(42); // number
console.log(result); // 42
```

Comment: Yes. I need to override it. It's basically an abstract method with given types.

Comment: No, the question is, "what do I have to change to make it work". I don't want to write a type in the function definition because I have multiple functions with multiple parameters. I don't want to repeat myself. As a bonus I would like to understand how it works under the hold and why it doesn't work like I did it